# Filtering through numpy arrays by one row's information

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

I am asking for help on filtering through numpy arrays. I currently have a numpy array which contains the following information:

```
[[x1_1, x1_2, ..., x1_n], [x2_1, x2_2, ..., x2_n], [y1, y2, ..., yn]
```

ie. the array is essentially a dataset where *x1, x2* are features (coordinates), and y is the output (value). Each data point has an appropriate *x1, x2*, and *y*, so for example, the info corresponding to data point *i* is *x1_i, x2_i*, and *yi*.

Now, I want to extract all the data points by filtering through y, meaning I want to know all the data points in which y > some value. In my case, I want the info (still with the same numpy structure) for all cases where y > 0. I don't really know how to do that -- I've been playing around with boolean indexing such as `d[0:2,y>0]` or `d[d[2]>0]`, but haven't gotten anywhere.

A clarifying example:

Given the dataset:

```
d = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [-0.1,-0.2,-0.3], [1,1,-1]]
```

I pull all points or instances where `y > 0`, ie. `d[2] > 0`, and it should return the values:

```
[[0.1, 0.2],[-0.1,-0.2],[1,1]]
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

d = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [-0.1,-0.2,-0.3], [1,1,-1]])
print (d)
[[ 0.1  0.2  0.3]
 [-0.1 -0.2 -0.3]
 [ 1.   1.  -1. ]]

#select last row by d[-1] 
print (d[-1]>0)
[ True  True False]

print (d[:,d[-1]>0])
[[ 0.1  0.2]
 [-0.1 -0.2]
 [ 1.   1. ]]
```

Comment: wow thanks! A question about the final line, the numpy searches through all of the array because you did :, but runs the condition from the arguments after the comma? So is it like the first statement before the comma filters through the rows, and the second statement after the comma filters through the columns?

Comment: Hmmm harder question for me, because I am `pandas` guy more as `numpy`, but I think `:` means select all 'rows' and then filter 'columns' by boolean mask. But I am not `100%` sure.

Comment: ah okay sounds good. Yeah pandas seems to be nicer, but I use numpy for ML and pandas for other data analysis :).